# Android show ProgressDialog from onPostExecute()

Tags: android, progressdialog

I have an `AsyncTask` and when showing the `ProgressDialog` from `onPreExecute()`, it works fine.

But in my app, I will first check with the `AsyncTask`, if there is any update pending to apply to the app and only when yes, I will show the `ProgressDialog`.

This happens in `onPostExecute()`. But when try to show the `ProgressDialog` from `onPostExecute()`, it never appears on the screen. As `onPreExecute()` and `onPostExecute()` are running on the UI it should be shown.

Any suggestions?

```
class ws_update extends AsyncTask<Integer, Integer, Integer>
{
    ProgressDialog pd;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pd = new ProgressDialog(NoticiasView.this);
        pd.setMessage(getResources().getString(R.string.ws_update));
        pd.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
        pd.setIndeterminate(false);
        pd.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
    }

    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(Integer... params)
    {
        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        try {
            String strURLact = Delegate.url_WS + "wsposts_v1.php";
            URL url = new URL(strURLact);

            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
            connection.setUseCaches(true);
            connection.setRequestProperty("content-type", "application/json;  charset=utf-8");

            DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream ());

            ...


        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if(connection != null)
                connection.disconnect();
        }

        return null;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values)
    {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        pd.setProgress(values[0]);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        if (jsonResponse == null) {
            return;
        }

        try {
            JSONArray aWS = jsonResponse.getJSONArray("wsposts");
            if (aWS.length() <= 0) {
                return;
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        pd.show();

        try {
            db.open();

            JSONArray aWS = jsonResponse.getJSONArray("wsposts");
            for (int iLoop=0; iLoop<aWS.length(); iLoop++) {
                JSONObject dicWS = aWS.getJSONObject(iLoop);
                JSONObject dicPost = dicWS.getJSONObject("post");
           ...

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        pd.dismiss();
    }
}
```

Comment: Post your code.

Comment: I think there is a small fundamental issue, progress dialog is meant to be shown when the asyn task is in progress meaning the doInBackground is going on. Is is to be associated with an activity which execute the task. Leaving all those aside you don't see it as postExecute ends immediately. What I suggest would be have some value set in post that triggers an alert dialog on UI whose lifecycle stays even after asyn task ends [with which all your variables are cleared].

Comment: The thing is, *pd.show()* then  *pd.dismiss()* directly after that.

Comment: SOLVED:Thanks. Solved it by adding a second AsyncTask, which is only called when values are ready for update. This shows now correctly de ProgressBar.